# Can't use "use Illuminate\Support\Collection;"

Tags: laravel, methods, collections, undefined

Getting errors like this when I try to use methods like all() or keyBy() The "use Illuminate\Support\Collection;" says its not using it.

`BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2025: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::all()`

```
$myArray = Item::whereitem_url($item->item_url)->all(); 
if( sizeof($myArray) > 0 ) 
{ 
    foreach ($myArray as $key => $value) 
    { 
       $myArray2[$value->iten_id] = $value; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some of your source code to the question?

Comment: $myArray = Item::whereitem_url($item->item_url)->all();

           if( sizeof($myArray) > 0 ) {
               foreach ($myArray as $key => $value) {
                 $myArray2[$value->iten_id] = $value;
              }
          }

Comment: I've added the code to your question. It's best to edit the question rather than squeeze the code into a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get "items" from DB, you can not use method `all()` together with `where()` clause, use `get()` instead.

```
$myArray = Item::whereItem_url($item->item_url)->get();
```

Method `all()` can be used only like this:

```
$myArray = Item::all();
```